# Programmatically set the background color of a list view item

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my app, I have to automatically set the background color of a `ListView` item, based on the string content of that list view item.

Currently, the app is using the below code:

```
    private void UpdateListView(string itemFromList, ListView listView)
    {
        int itemListPosition = listViewAdapter.GetPosition(itemFromList);
        listView.SetItemChecked(itemListPosition, true);

        View child = listView.GetChildAt(itemListPosition);

        if (child != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listViewAdapter.Count; i++)
            {
                View otherChild = listView.GetChildAt(i);

                if (otherChild != null)
                {
                    otherChild.SetBackgroundColor(defaultColor);
                }
            }

            child.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
        }
    }
```

where `listViewAdapter` is a global variable in the `MainActivity` class defined as below into the `onCreate` method:

```
listViewAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, settingItems);
listView.Adapter = listViewAdapter;
```

and `settingItems` is just a global variable defined as a list of strings.

The above code was working fine, so the background color of a given list view item was changing to green and the rest of the list view items to the default color, until the list view added a vertical scroll to it.

Now after the list view got more items and a vertical scroll all the time the

```
View child = listView.GetChildAt(itemListPosition);
```

`child` object from the above call is null. Consequently, I can't access anymore the items from the list view based on their position. Do you know how can I work around this?

Comment: Create a custom `Adapter` inside the `getView()` method simply place a `if` statement that verifies whether your criteria has been met then change the properties for that `View` accordingly. Good Luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the background of particular item of ListView programatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455569/how-to-change-the-background-of-particular-item-of-listview-programatically-andr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a demo in `GetView` method, set the item background color, you could refer to it.

This is GIF of demo.

[image]

You could change code in the `GetView` method of listview adapter. I do not know which items you want to change in listview, so I set the position in 1,3,5. you could change it by yourself.

`MyAdapter.cs`

```
   class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<ColorDemo>
{
    Activity context;
    List<ColorDemo> colors { get; set; }
    public MyAdapter(Activity context , List<ColorDemo> colors)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.colors = colors;

    }

    public override ColorDemo this[int position] {
        get
        {
            return colors[position];
        }
    }

    public override int Count => colors.Count;



    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View newView = convertView;
        if (newView == null)
            newView = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemView, null);
        newView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_tv).Text = colors[position].ColorName;
        if (position==1|| position == 3|| position == 5)
        {
            newView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_tv).SetBackgroundColor( Color.Blue);

        }
        else
        {
            newView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_tv).SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);

        }

       return newView;

    }
}
```

The following is `activity_main.axml` and `ItemView.axml`, you could customize items in the listview by ItemView

`activity_main.axml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/lv_color"
     />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

`ItemView.axml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this text"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_tv"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The following code is related to the MainActivity.cs

`MainActivity.cs`

```
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        ListView lv_color = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv_color);
       // lv_color.SetItemChecked(2,true);
        List<ColorDemo> colors = new List<ColorDemo>();
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("red"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("red"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("red"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("red"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("red"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("red"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));
        colors.Add(new ColorDemo("green"));

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,colors);
        lv_color.Adapter=myAdapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: First I want to thank you for this example. Secondly I want to mention that the example is somehow hard coded meaning that all the time you make the second item from list with a blue background. Where in my case this list item can have the blue background if some conditions are meet but also in can have the red background if other conditions are meet. Can your example be extended to support also this ?

Comment: @clock ,Yes,you could change the code of getView() in MyAdatper,i set the postion 1,3,5 to change background color,you can change the color with postion by your demand, or you could provide your demand, i will try to coding it.

Comment: what I need to achieve is that the background color of an item may change. Let's say I got a list with nearby upcoming local events ( local cinema movies, shopping discounts, etc ) . Each this event has a starting date. These events are stored into the view list. When the current date gets close to the date of an event from the list, the event from the list gets automatically selected and the background color of it changes so that the user can see it better.