# Change ListView item background color programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's say we have ListView of basic text items:

```
package cz.nanuq.test

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Init listView
        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)

        var values : Array<String> = arrayOf("foo", "bar", "baz", "boo")
        var adapter : ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values)
        listView.setAdapter(adapter)

        // Change background color of one listView item
        var index : Int = 2               // can change dynamically
        var bgColor : String = '#123456'  // can change dynamically
        //...how? 
    }

}
```

Now I want to change background color of item with index 2 to "#123456".

How to do that?

---

P.S. For this simple task I'm looking for simple solution. Something like:

```
listView.getItem(index).setAttribute("background", bgColor)
```

Basically I just need to access ListView's sub-component and change it's attribute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017402/7666442

Comment: Use need to create Custom Adapter and custom layout of item.

Comment: You can extend `ArrayAdapter`, and override `getView` method

Comment: You can write your own custom adapter and easily can do it like if you use relative layout then
 layout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.yellow);

Comment: @Zoe Ok, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

I just used code from question And got expected result. This definitely helps & Simplest way. we can implement the adapter and change the views like we want. Please try the below code.

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val values: Array<String> = arrayOf("foo", "bar", "baz", "boo")

    // Change background color of one listView item
    private var index: Int = 0               // can change dynamically®
    private var bgColor: String = "#ffffff"  // can change dynamically

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Init listView
        val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.listView)

        val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> =
            object : ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values) {
                override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
                    val v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)

                    val tv = v.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1)

                    if (index == position) {
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bgColor))
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                    } else {
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                    }

                    return v
                }
            }

        listView.adapter = adapter


        // For -- Explanation / testing purpose, I used handler here.
        update(adapter)
    }

    private fun update(adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>) {

        // For -- Explanation / testing purpose, I used handler here.

        Handler().postDelayed({
            index = 0
            bgColor = "#123456"
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }, 1000)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            index = 1
            bgColor = "#c544fc"
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }, 2000)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            index = 2
            bgColor = "#123456"
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }, 3000)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            index = 3
            bgColor = "#c544fc"
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            // For -- Explanation / testing purpose, (REPEATING / LOOPING).
            update(adapter)
        }, 4000)
    }
}
```

The result as follows. Happy Coding :)

[image: Divakar Murugesh's Answer]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background color of a specific item, you need to set it inside your **onBindViewHolder** method in your CustomAdapter class. This is my code for setting the 5th item of my recyclerview.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProfileDetails profileDetails = profileDetailsList.get(position);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(profileDetails.getIcon());
        holder.label.setText(profileDetails.getLabel());
        holder.details.setText(profileDetails.getDetail());

        if(position == 4)
        {
            holder.details.setMaxLines(3);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.btn_border);
            holder.details.setMinHeight(90);
            holder.itemView.setMinimumHeight(90);
            holder.itemView.setPadding(0,20,0,50);
        }
    }
```

**holder.details.setMaxLines(3)** is my code for programmatically setting the maxLines of the TextView of my 5th item. Other textView is set to 1 as their maxLines.

**holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.btn_border);** is my code to set the background of my 5th item. Note that you need to create a drawable for your color. This won't work if you just set a color from color.xml.

**holder.itemView.setMinimumHeight(90);** is my code to manipulate the height of the TextView and **holder.itemView.setPadding(0,20,0,50);** for the padding left, padding top, padding right and padding bototm.

Refer to the screenshot below for the final output.

[image: RecyclerView]